# PHP AES-128-CBC Encryption and Decryption

Tags: php, encryption

I have a problem with my encryption decryption code in PHP. I created a simple AES-128-CBC type process to decrypt the following values but failed to get expected values. All the values are in hexadecimal:

Input: 34373934343630303031323731323238

Key: 193932aca22387b868c8593a6bf38872

IV: 2e221a3f4941b04a8f68f3bb8612596f

I can get correct value from online tool https://cryptii.com/pipes/aes-encryption. Please help me. Thanks.

My PHP code:

```
<?php 
$input = '34373934343630303031323731323238';
$method = 'aes-128-cbc';
$key = '193932aca22387b868c8593a6bf38872';
$iv = '2e221a3f4941b04a8f68f3bb8612596f';

$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($input, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

echo 'Encrypted value: '.$encrypted;
?>
```

Expected output: 4aad176e05980f02593be7e15b9458a587f4c36bbf9a6510c2c4b8ab842ca707

Comment: This might be an encoding problem, did you see [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php)

Comment: You said it yourself: all values are hexadecimal. So decode them!

Comment: @kelalaka Yes I have checked from php.net. I tried converting all values to hexadecimal but still failed to get the expected result.

Comment: @Peter I tried but I believe something wrong with my key and IV. I followed the guideline to form 16 bytes of key and IV to decode the expected value but still failed to get back input value.

Comment: Convert `$input`, `$key` and `$iv` from a hexadecimal string to the corresponding binary string with [`hex2bin`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php), and `$encrypted` from a binary string to the corresponding hexadecimal string with the inverse function [`bin2hex`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php). Then the result matches the expected value.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks Sir! I got the value from the conversion for both values in double ways. Your help is really appreciated!